How to change the background color of a specific area in Jetpack Compose?
I'm working on a Jetpack Compose project, and I need to change the background color of a specific area within a screen. Here's what I have so far:
@Composable
fun Bgcolor() {
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(16.dp)
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text("This is the box")
    }
    }
 }

I want to move this Box upwards and change its background color. How can I achieve this? I've tried using the offset modifier, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly. Here is what I tried:
@Composable
fun BgcolorWithOffset() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(200.dp)
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .padding(16.dp)
                .offset(y = (-50).dp)
        ) {
            Text("This is the moved box", color = Color.Black)
        }
    }
}

The box does not move up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The order of modifier matters in compose. Try placing offset before applying background. And it would be easy to answer if you provide pictural explanation(about your expectations)
